# Switch statement for UserDefaults (Swift-Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, switch-statement

I would like to know how i could do a switch-case/any good statement for user defaults instead of using if-else because as you can see from my code, i'm using 3 if statements which is abit redundant and ugly.
The purpose of this view controller is for a "Pick a card" game, the user gets to pick 3 cards each time and if he/she selects a card, they will not be able to select that particular card again.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var buttona: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var buttonb: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var buttonc: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       if (UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dissapear") == 1)
       {
           buttona.setImage(UIImage(named: "wildcardbackingblack.png"), for: .normal)
           buttona.isEnabled = false
       }

       if (UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dissapear2") == 1)
       {
           buttonb.setImage(UIImage(named: "wildcardbackingblack.png"), for: .normal)
           buttonb.isEnabled = false
       }

       if (UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dissapear3") == 1)
       {
           buttonc.setImage(UIImage(named: "wildcardbackingblack.png"), for: .normal)
           buttonc.isEnabled = false
       }
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   @IBAction func Button1(_ sender: Any) {
      UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey:"dissapear")
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "show", sender: nil)         
   }

   @IBAction func Button2(_ sender: Any) {
      UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey:"dissapear2")
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "show", sender: nil)
   }

   @IBAction func Button3(_ sender: Any) {
      UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey:"dissapear3")
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "show", sender: nil)
    }
 }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You repeat yourself too much. Extract common code into functions, loop over `[(buttona, "dissapear"), (buttonb, "dissapear2"), (buttonc, "dissapear3")]`, and call it

Comment: @Alexander and how do u do that exactly? I'm still quite new to swift apologies

Answer (score 1):

```
    func updateCard(button: UIButton, image: String, isEnabled: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyc {
            button.setImage(UIImage(named:image), for: .normal)
            button.isEnabled = isEnabled
        }
    }

    .
    .
    .

    let option : Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dissapear")
    switch (option) {
        case 1:
            self.updateCard(button: ..., image:"wildcardbackingblack.png", isEnabled: false)
        case 2:                       
            self.updateCard(button: ..., image:"wildcardbackingblack.png", isEnabled: false)
        case 3:
            self.updateCard(button: ..., image:"wildcardbackingblack.png", isEnabled: false)
        default:
            self.updateCard(button: ..., image:"default.png", isEnabled: false)
    } 
//Save the different integer value in same key user defaults.

 @IBAction func Button1(_ sender: Any) {
      UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey:"dissapear")
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "show", sender: nil)         
   }

   @IBAction func Button2(_ sender: Any) {
      UserDefaults.standard.set(2, forKey:"dissapear")
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "show", sender: nil)
   }

   @IBAction func Button3(_ sender: Any) {
      UserDefaults.standard.set(3, forKey:"dissapear")
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "show", sender: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Your answer might helpful but Just posting code is not the best answer. if you add some explanation then it will helpful to others facing same problem. so it is good habit to add some info related to answer :)

Comment: OP should replace the 1/2/3 with more meaningful values (the names of the cards?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would write this code, if I were sticking to the same UserDefaults storage. Note: you need to reconnect `cardPressed(_:)` to every button/card

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var buttonA: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var buttonB: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var buttonC: UIButton!

    let buttonKeyPairs: [(button: UIButton, key: String)] = [
        (buttonA, "dissapear"),
        (buttonB, "dissapear2"),
        (buttonC, "dissapear3"),
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for (button, key) in buttonKeyPairs
            where UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: key) == 1 {

            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "wildcardbackingblack.png"), for: .normal)
            button.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let key: String
        switch UIButton {
            case buttonA: key = "dissapear"
            case buttonB: key = "dissapear2"
            case buttonC: key = "dissapear3"
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: key)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "show", sender: self)         
    }
}
```